# If Jobs in a stream in CUDA is blocking

Tags: concurrency, stream, cuda

If some jobs are enqueued in a stream, when a job in the stream launches, would it blocks the stream and other jobs in stream would wait until current job finishes, or if there is resource available for the stream, following jobs also would be launched concurrently.

Comment: What do you mean by "jobs"? CUDA kernels?

Comment: @talonmies CUDA kernels, async memory copy

Comment: I think async memcpy is not a CUDA kernel. Why do not you use a [CUDA profiler timeline](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#timeline-view) to get the answer?

Comment: @User81862311 I noted that I enqueued JOBS in a stream which includes kernel launch and async memory copy `cudaMemcpyAsync`. 
Thanks using cuda profiler timeline is good idea.

Comment: cuda stream semantics dictate that for any work  issued into a single stream, that work is executed in issue order.  Item B, issued after item A, does not begin until item A is complete.

Comment: @RobertCrovella you mean jobs within one stream is blocking, and when job A launches job B and C and  ... should wait until job A finishes and then B launches. I know that they are in order, but my question is if there is resource available for job B while job A is running, job B will be launched?

Comment: @Person.Woman.Man.Camera.TV But the problem with your solution is that it can not be conclusive, since for one scenario in one device it can be blocking but in another one, not.

Answer (score 1):

I discussed with a NVidia Staff about the question and it was the result.
**Async memory copy and launching kernel in default stream and within user-defined stream are non-blocking.**